# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Desktop 64-bit - iso custom - Automatically run a bash script after installation is complete

Tags: 20.04, bash, custom-distributions

The installation is done normally, i.e. on disk (No VM)
I have a script in which there are commands to be executed as a normal user and others as superuser. For example:

post-install_script.sh

```
sudo operation1
operation2
operation3
sudo operation4
operation5
...
```

This script must be run before Ubuntu sends the "Installation completed" notification but after all other installation operations (such as user creation).
There are many answers on the internet but none simple enough for me to understand how to proceed in my particular case.

Comment: If you have done your research properly, then you already know that your question should specify whether the install is Ubuntu Server or Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Core or something else, and whether the install is taking place on Bare Metal, in a VM, or on a Cloud server. Those choices will determine whether you use Preseed files Cloud-Init, or other tools.

Comment: @user535733 Ok, I have edited title and question